# Ceiling Fan with remote not turning on properly with wall switch

Tags: lighting, switch, ceiling-fan

Installed Arrano Ceiling Fan w/remote. Light was flickering so I replace dimmer wall switch. Now light will not go on until I turn switch on then off then on again

Comment: Does the remote have light controls on it?

Comment: Clearly there is something wrong.  But based on what little information you have provided there is nothing that can be offered.  Please describe EXACTLY what you have and how it's connected.  A photo or two would be very helpful.

Comment: Note that those pics should be [edit]ed into your post and would be taken (with the power off) of the switch wiring (connections to the switch, showing the wires leading into the back of the box) and the wiring connections to the fan/light. Often, flickering lights are indicative of loose connections and not necessarily faulty hardware.